# How to have a single html file to display multiple page?

Tags: php, html, dynamic, binding

I new to web designing, I'm currently working on a hobby project a e-commerce site.

My problems is that I don't want to link single page to every products. It creates a huge collection of `HTML` files, instead of that I want to **DYNAMICALLY** get data.

**For eg:**

If an *index.html* has `<p>selected item</p>`. I want it to display `<p>item1</p><p>item2</p><p>item3</p>` from another `HTML` file like *products.html* respectively when item1 or item2 or item3 is selected using `class` or `id`. I'm open to other choice like using framework etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not php foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PHP` `foreach` for this.

I suggest you take a look at the php.net documentation about this: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

It will allow you to create an `array` and display the items you want where they need to be displayed. This can be based on `ID` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ajax and jquery for updating the same html page. Also you can learn use Angular to create single page applications(SPAs). https://www.w3schools.com/angular/